# Swift 3 alamofire swiftyjson subscript

Tags: ios, json, swift3, alamofire, swifty-json

I don't know why my code doesn't work, my result is always nil.
I integrated alamofire and swiftyjson this is my code:

```
let urlString = "myurl"

let params: Parameters = [
    "accessProvider": AccessProvider,
    "inputToken": AccessToken
]


Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody)
    .responseJSON { response in
        if let responseObject = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(responseObject)")

            let json = JSON(responseObject)

            let path: [JSONSubscriptType] = ["user","id"]
            let name = json[path].string
            print("AAAAA")
            print(name)
        }
}
```

I can read the first part of user but the second one with id is always nil.
this is the response json:

```
{
  "responseCode": 0,
  "responseDescription": "OK",
  "user": "{"id":"MAIL",
        "nickname":"MYNAME",
        "level":"U",
        "status":"A",
        "sex":null,
        "ageGroup":null,
        "address":null,
        "latitude":null,
        "longitude":null,
        "creation_timestamp":"2017-05-10 18:40:21",
        "notification":"1",
        "last_login":"2017-05-11 18:32:07",
        "mobilePreference":null,
        "sport":null,
        "spot":null,
        "token":"LONGTOKENID"}"
}
```

Comment: The value for key `user` seems to be another JSON string. Are you responsible for the server side? If yes, consider to send a dictionary.

Comment: i'm not the responsible of server side, how i can avoid the problem?

Comment: You need to deserialize the string (with SwiftyJSON) to a dictionary.

Comment: can i have a little bit of code?, i'm new to ios, sorry for the disturb.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't use SwiftyJSON but most likely there is an `init` method taking a literal string.

Comment: can you share the url or webservice from which you are downloading data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you vadian,
i solved the question with your indication,
if anyone have the same problem you can solve like this:
//Initialize the first json:

```
let json = JSON(responseObject)
```

//Extract the second Json to String

```
let path: [JSONSubscriptType] = ["user"]
let name = json[path].string
```

//Initialize the second json from string

```
if let dataFromString = name?.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) 
let jsonuser = JSON(data: dataFromString)
```

//Access to the data

Thank you all,
Have nice day.